# UISearchBar calls API everytime a letter is typed and not on Searchbutton click

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm working on a student project.

At this point our application can call the API and reload the data, but only if I call the `XMLParser` inside `textDidChange`.

Meaning: It calls and reloads correctly every time a letter is typed in `UISearchBar`. I Want the call and reload to only happen when the user clicks on the Search button, but the same code that works in `textDidChange` doesn't work in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`.

Instead.. The method calls the API only when the searchbutton is pressed **(good)**, receives the the same information like with `textDidChange`  **(good)** but doesn't reload the `UITableView` **(bad)**.

I have searched all over Stack Overflow for the answer to my problem, so I thought I'd post a question instead:)

All of the examples that I've come across only shows how to display the content of an array that matches the users criteria when the user types (contactlist), but doesn't show how to use the searchbutton to reload the `UITableView` correctly.

Why does the same exact code reload correctly in the delegate method

`- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`

but not in

`- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar`?

As I said, NSLog prints out the correct data to load the `UITableview` when the searchButton is clicked, so that is not the problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? :)

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = @"searchCell";
    
    SearchCell *cell = nil;
    
    cell = (SearchCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SearchCell class]]) {
                cell = (SearchCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    Search *currentSearch = [[searchxmlParser searchhits] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    cell.track_label.text = [currentSearch track];
    cell.artist_label.text = [currentSearch artist];
    
    return cell;
}
```

The requested delegate methods:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    
    NSString *searchurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=%@", [self urlEncodeValue:searchText]];
    
    xmlParser = [[SearchXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:searchurl];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    
    NSString *searchurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=%@", [self urlEncodeValue:theSearchBar.text]];

    xmlParser = [[SearchXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:searchurl];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[searchxmlParser searchhits] count];
}
```

Comment: yes it was, and thanks for my time while i was editing your question

Comment: do you use an search display controller? Or not?

Comment: Thank you :) yes, im using a search display controller :)

Comment: How does your cell for row at index path look? Do you test to see witch table view is displayed? Add some code..

Comment: @terenteIonutAlexandru you didn't got them all bro. @_AlexanderNorway I suggest posting your code in both delegate methods so we can see what you do wrong there.

Comment: Just some spacing because I could not read it.

Comment: can u show the code.. in - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText and - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar

Comment: @TerenteIonutAlexandru cellForRowAtIndexPath is now added in the orginal post :)

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I have added both to the original post :)

Comment: @vishy : I have added both to the original post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In your h file you should have declared 2 arrays one with the original dataSource and one with filtredValues. Alloc them in viewDidLoad and release in dealloc.

In cellForRowAtIndexPat and in umberOfRowsInSection you should test witch tableView is displayed and return desired values.

```
if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
// search view population
} else {
// all data view population
}
```

And with this approach you can use live search by filtring dataSource array and put the values in filtredArray.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction :) This post was exactly what I needed to realise that Im actually working with two tableViews instead of one. Using the code you provided above, it became obvious that my code reloaded tableview instead of reloading searchResultsTableView.(It switches to searchResultsTableView when SearchButton is clicked). The search now works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set yourself as the delegate of search bar and override the default behavior of the delegate search bar delegate `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:`.

The default implementation of this will do a search with each key press.  All you have to do is return `NO` in the method:

```
- (BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: That didnt help. It seems that I can only reload the tableview from inside the textDidChange. With the return of the method you mentioned as NO, I cant get anything to reload, but if I use YES, and put only a reload in textDidChange; then this happens: I write in a song name, hit enter, I get the data as I should(NSLog), but nothing appears in the tableview. To get the results like I want in the tableview; I actually have to go up to the searchfield and press space after having clicked the searchbuttonspace.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly implement numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection ?

Please show the code for these two methods.

Addition:

If you put

```
NSLog(@" number of rows in section = %d", [[searchxmlParser searchhits] count]);
```

what does it output?

Comment: I have added them to the original post :)

Comment: I have fixed the problem now :) (Check comment on the post above this one). However.. I now need to clear the tableview after a search has been preformed. Any tips on how im to do that in my case? :)

Comment: Assuming you mean to empty the searchResultsTableView to go back to the full list, if you create your searchResultsTableview programmatically you could just ditch it when not needed anymore and recreate it each time you need it.

Comment: The full list is something I dont ever need. Its supposed to only show searchResultsTableview when the searchbutton is pressed. The best way around this will just be to add a black view ontop of the table that is hidden until the user presses the search button. I need to do this anyhow, since I need to cover up the "No results" message while typing. Thanks for your input! :)